# Two way dead lettering between work queue and retry queue

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to implement dead lettering in recursive way. I have two queues, a main queue and a retry queue for it.
The messages will first be put in the main queue. When there is a exception during consumer process, it throws AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException so that the message gets removed from queue and added to the retry queue. It sits there for 5 secs, and then get added to tail of the work queue again.
when the consumer throws 'AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException', it does not get delivered to the retry queue

Could you help me how i can resolve this?

Below is the configuration, producer and consumer files.

producer config:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory()
    connectionFactory.setUsername(userName)
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password)
    connectionFactory.setAddresses(hosts)
    return connectionFactory
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory())
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory())
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter()
}

@Bean
public DirectExchange searchNotificationExchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("search.notification.exchange", false, true)
}

@Bean
public Queue searchNotificationQueue() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>()
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "search.notification.retry.exchange")
    return new Queue(SEARCH_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, args)
}

@Bean
public Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(searchNotificationQueue()).to(searchNotificationExchange()).with(SEARCH_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE_NAME);
}

@Bean
public DirectExchange searchNotificationRetryExchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("search.notification.retry.exchange", false, true)
}

@Bean
public Queue searchNotificationRetryQueue() {
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>()
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "search.notification.exchange")
    args.put("x-message-ttl",5000)
    return new Queue(SEARCH_NOTIFICATION_RETRY_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, args)
}

@Bean
public Binding retryBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(searchNotificationRetryQueue()).to(searchNotificationRetryExchange()).with(SEARCH_NOTIFICATION_RETRY_QUEUE_NAME);
}
```

Consumer config that extend from producer config

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory()
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory())
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3)
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10)
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter())
    return factory
}
```

producer:

```
try {
                    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitConfiguration.SEARCH_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE_NAME, sd);
                    println sd.deliveryId
                } catch(AmqpException amqbe) {
                    log.error("Error putting message into search notification queue.", amqbe)
                }
```

Consumer:

```
@RabbitListener(queues =RabbitConfiguration.SEARCH_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE_NAME)
public void handleMessage(SearchNotificationMQMessage messageBody, Message message) {
try {
//process message
}  catch(Throwable t) {

        if(message.messageProperties.deliveryTag < 3) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException()
        }
    }
```